# 5 balanced masses on wheel with different distances between them

Tags: geometry, flywheels

I'm looking for a way to calculate possible balanced positions of 5 equal masses on the circumference of a spinning wheel such that the distance along the circumference between the masses are all different, and no distance is an integer multiple of any of other the other distances. This is like the balanced centrifuge problem, but without defined slots.

Masses arranged in a 5 point star would be balanced, but the distances would all be the same. 3 masses in an equilateral triangle with 2 additional masses places across from each other would also be balanced, but distances between the 3 masses would be the same, and the distances between the 2 are the same clockwise and counter clockwise. Is there a possible arrangement of 5 masses where all the distances are different?

Comment: Evaluate for each mass at its distance.

Comment: Do you want to do this computationally, or from first principles, or what?  It may be that what you want isn't possible, but I'm not sure what branch of mathematics to point you to in order to find out whether that's the case or not.  I can give you an easy-ish algorithm on how to determine _whether_ your set of masses is balanced, but not one that just coughs up every possible arrangement.

Comment: For context, I'm trying to figure out the geometry for 3D printing a wheel in which I can embed magnets on the circumference to create a rotary magnetic bow as outlined here https://github.com/spDuchamp/OSCRMB

The goal with this particular question of balanced 5 magnet arrangement of magnets is to create a wheel where the distances between the magnets are all different and no distance is an integer multiple of the other. I'm trying to experiment to see if I can make a rotary magnetic bow that has no harmonic locking like the 6 arrangement bow I use as outlined on that github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw a vector diagram of the unbalance force due to each of the 5 masses. Put each vector nose to tail and if they come back to the origin then its balanced. An easy way to think about this vector chain is a chain with 5 equal length links in a loop. Any of its infinitely many configurations is balanced.

Comment: Hmmm.   This is definitely helpful! I need to try to figure out a program that can work this out for me, but I can totally see how deforming a pentagon while keeping the sides the same length will yield the result.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinite positions that will qualify for the balance.

Let's assume we suspend a wheel of radius 1 from its center with 5 equal masses P from a string.

An easy answer is to put the masses at the corners of a pentagon with the top corner at point A(0, 1) and annotating counterclockwise,B at 90+72 = 162, thus B (cos 162, sin162)=B(-0.951, 0.309) ; C(-0.587,-0.809): D(0.587, -0.809); E (0.951, 0.309).

Now we move points C and D down by a random amount, say 0.02 to the new ordinate y=-0.809 -0.02=0.829. The abscissa will change following $sin^2+ cos^2=1$ but we are not concerned with that.

All we need to do is move B and E up to the new elevation of Y2. Due to the symmetry, we don't worry about changes in x coordinate.

For the centroid to pass through the origin.

$$ Y_o= 0 =\frac{1*p+2Y_2*p-2p*0.829}{5p}$$
$$p+2Y_2p-1.658p=0$$
$$p(1+2Y_2-1.658)=0$$
$$2Y_2=0.658 \quad Y_2=0.329$$
The fact that the change in the ordinate of the B and C are equal is due to rounding of arithmetic, normally they aren't.

When the wheel is balanced about the Y axis and the X axis, it is in polar balance.

We could repeat this by turning the wheel to B at the top, etc.

There are many other configurations, such as perturbing 1, and 2, or3 points.

Comment: Cemetery? Symmetry possibly.

Comment: Hmm. If you move points C and D by just translating the y like that, they are no longer on the circumference of the wheel. I need them bound to the circumference of the wheel.  I think the reply that mentioned just adding the vectors together is on track to answer this. If I distort a pentagon while keeping the sides all the same length, and then translate all the "tails" together, I'd have my configuration. I think, but not sure.

Comment: @spDuchamp, yes of course the abscissa will have to change to stay on the circle. but that is not our concern. how ever I edited my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Greg Locock's answer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/54938/41450) I made this diagram that starts off with a balanced arrangement and then I moved the vectors to create these pentagons. This particular balanced arrangement doesn't meet the criteria that the distances be non-integer multiples of other distances, but this is definitely a step closer to the solution I'm seeking.
[image: 5 balanced vectors translated into pentagons]

Here is a diagram of fixing two of the vectors (black arrows) and moving the other vectors (red arrows) to find a new balanced arrangements.
[image: moving foci on pentagon to find new balanced positions]